# Retrofit and Jackson: JsonParseException on String response

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit

I am using retrofit(**version 1.9**) and jackson(**jackson-converter 1.9**). We have API which often sends response in form of raw Strings.

Our api client is the following:

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
            .setConverter(new JacksonConverter())
```

Here is the basic request:

```
api.basicPostRequest(Sample object, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {

        })
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
```

Here is the http response we got:

```
<--- HTTP 200 https://sample url (606ms)
Date: Fri, 22 Apr 2016 13:57:46 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1461331000541
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1461331001011

OK
```

However execution continues in `public void failure(RetrofitError error)` and retrofit gives this error:

```
 ERROR: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: 
 Unrecognized token 'OK': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') 
 at [Source: retrofit.
 ExceptionCatchingTypedInput$ExceptionCatchingInputStream@5290df1c; line: 1, column: 5]
```

Is this bug or I am doing wrong or missing something?

With regards

Comment: It seems your server is returning "OK" instead of "true" or "false" for a boolean parameter.

Comment: @DeeV, I am not expecting `boolean` value. I am expecting `String` as `new Callback<String>()`

Comment: Your server returns `OK`, but that's not a valid JSON value. So an exception is sure to happen.

Comment: @Tomik, Yeah I know this. Recently I was using retrofit without assigning converters and `OK` responses were continued on `onSuccess` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Retrofit 1.x, if you need something like this, the way is to make your request return `retrofit.client.Response`, and then get the body content yourself through the stream located in `Response.getBody().in()`.

Comment: Yeah, I see this only way to handle it. How it is handled in Retrofit 2.x?

Comment: In Retrofit 2.x, you can make your request return a `okhttp3.ResponseBody` and then just call its `string()` method.

Comment: Thanks for advice.